# Facebook FQL returning inconsistent results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've got a question around why some items are not returning via a Facebook FQL query.

The following query:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20page_id,%20name,%20type,%20fan_count%20from%20page%20where%20name=%27Bauhaus%27%20and%20type%20=%20%27MUSICIAN/BAND%27%20order%20by%20fan_count%20desc
```

Is supposed to return me pages whose name = 'Bauhaus' and type is 'Musician/Band'.  The result is:

```
<fql_query_response list="true">
<page>
<page_id>186907181359330</page_id>
<name>Bauhaus</name>
<type>MUSICIAN/BAND</type>
<fan_count>1</fan_count>
</page>
<page>
<page_id>175833025805207</page_id>
<name>Bauhaus</name>
<type>MUSICIAN/BAND</type>
<fan_count>0</fan_count>
</page>
</fql_query_response>
```

If I then add a constraint, page_id=109194179106090, which doesn't appear in the above list: `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20page_id,%20name,%20type,%20fan_count%20from%20page%20where%20page_id%20=%20109194179106090`, I get this result:

```
<fql_query_response list="true">
<page>
<page_id>109194179106090</page_id>
<name>Bauhaus</name>
<type>MUSICIAN/BAND</type>
<fan_count>100527</fan_count>
</page>
</fql_query_response>
```

Why should adding a constraint return me an item that isn't in the original query?

Answer (score 1):

In FQL, adding a constraint of a page id automatically adds it to the query, assuming that you know exactly what you want and won't be narrowing it down by other criteria.

Comment: Ah--that's helpful in explaining why it gets added in that case--but not the broader question (which I should have asked more explicitly) of why that same row doesn't return when I issue the first query.  That is, since the name = "Bauhaus' and the type = 'Musician/Band', why do I get 2 returns but not the specific item I'm looking for in the first query.  Thanks for explaining the other behavior though.